# Dynamics of simple atwood machine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

I am a student and need help with my homework:

In this figure two masses m1 and
m2 have been suspended from either side of the pulley
**m2>m1**

[image: Atwood machine]

As a result
*The blocks move with equal acceleration(a)*

Then

**m2g-T=m2a [down]**

**T-m1g=m1a [up]**

Since m2>m1

**m2a>m1a**       -(i)

But *displacement is equal for each block [acceleration is equal]*

**As
s=ut+1/2at^2**

And u=0 in both cases

Multiplying equation (i) by s,

m2a×s > m1a×s

*But remaining within the scope of  classical mechanics,*

*This violates the **law of conservation of energy***

My question is:

***How is this possible?***

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is incomplete.  Mass $m_2$ loses more gravitational potential energy than mass $m_1$ gains, but both masses gain kinetic energy as they move faster and faster while mass $m_2$ is falling.  If you do a complete energy balance for both masses, you will find that the "missing" part of the gravitational potential energy is equal to the kinetic energy of the two moving masses.